# Mapping arrays into nice looking text

Tags: python, arrays, string, mapping

How to map array strings with specific spacing and text?

Say I have,

```
a = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8])
b = np.array([100, 400, 600, 800])
```

Desired output when printing:

```
Position    Magnitude
2 m         100 kg
4 m         400 kg     
6 m         600 kg    
8 m         800 kg
```

I have tried something like this, but does not show what I want

```
print("\n "+ ' '.join(map(str, a)))
```

So as can be seen, I want the unit 'm' and 'kg' to come right after each element in list a and b. The lists contains only numbers.

Comment: Do you want to export the output in a text file or just display in console ?

Comment: @AlexandreB. Just show in console (as shown above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`format()` gives you a whole [mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#formatspec) for laying out rows. Here's a simple use case for fixed-with columns:

```
a = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8])
b = np.array([100, 400, 600, 800])

print('{} {:>14}'.format('Position','Magnitude'))
for m, kg in zip(a,b):
    print('{} m{:>14} kg'.format(m, kg))
```

**prints**

```
Position      Magnitude
2 m           100 kg
4 m           400 kg
6 m           600 kg
8 m           800 kg
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with `pandas` (the output is without the `#`...):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8])
b = np.array([100, 400, 600, 800])


df = pd.DataFrame({"Position": [str(pos) + " m" for pos in a],
                    "Magnitude": [str(mag) + " kg" for mag in b]})


print(df.to_string(index=False))
# Position Magnitude
#      2 m    100 kg
#      4 m    400 kg
#      6 m    600 kg
#      8 m    800 kg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over the two lists simultaneously using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and print the elements.

I have used tabs `\t` to create the necessary spacing, but a combination of spaces and tabs can be played around, along with other formatting parameters to improve the formatting

```
print('Position\tMagnitude')

#Iterate over the arrays simultaneously
for pos, mag in zip(a,b):

    #Print the elements
    print(f'{pos} m\t\t\t{mag} kg')
```

The output will be

```
Position    Magnitude
2 m         100 kg
4 m         400 kg
6 m         600 kg
8 m         800 kg
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this, you'll have the requested output. `zip` just iterate two for cycles at the same time. In this case, a1 will iterate over a vector, while b1 will iterate over b vector.

```
a = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8])
b = np.array([100, 400, 600, 800])
print('Position\t Magnitude')
for a1, b1 in zip(a,b):
    print(a1,'m\t\t',b1,'kg')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use operations on this further rather than just a print, it's better to use `pandas` module:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a, b)), colums=['Position', 'Magnitude'])

df['Position'] = df['Position'].astype(str) + ' m'
df['Magnitude'] = df['Magnitude'].astype(str) + ' kg'

print(df)
```